# Cannot see what I'm typing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I really like the new beta theme, I guess it is much more attractive to newcomers than the sketchy one (which I also liked). Thanks a lot!

However I'm slightly embarrassed because I can't read what I type, both in the title and in the body of a post. I never encountered the problem on other StackExchange sites. The symptoms corresponds to some *css* illness where only one among `background-color` or `color` is defined (in this case `background-color`.) The foreground is set to my system default which is close enough to the specified background so that I cant see it.

Please choose to specify both or none, but not only one. Thank you!

Ah it's expected to be a question… Hum, can someone fix this? ;-)

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing (or not seeing :))?

Comment: @Anna I think my diagnostic of the problem is pretty clear: Please remove the `background: #fff` field for the `textarea` field in the css stylesheet, or alternatively add a properly defined `color` property. Btw the validation service finds [136 errors](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.cs.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F16%2Fcannot-see-what-im-typing&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=true&lang=en) in the stylesheet (not counting warnings…)

Comment: Oh, and if you really want to know: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0.

Comment: I'm looking into this now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I removed the explicit white background color from input fields and textarea. This change will be in the next production build. Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem! You might also consider adding a `color:` to the tags input field (but that's less problematic as they show up with readable colors in bubbles eventually).